# how can you check the data type of a MDX Measure in icCube?

Tags: iccube

I am using a project-to-date calculated member in a STATS dimension that aggregates the data. But I am also using string measures (e.g. to display some text).

Now, the string measures show an error when using the PTD view:
"Aggregation SUM is not supported for datatype string".

The solution, is to check on the datatype prior to aggregating it, but how can you do that.

In SSAS MDX, there is the VBA function called "typename()", does something exist for icCube as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since icCube 6.5.1 the following MDX functions are available:

```
VarTypeName   ( arg ) : the type of the MDX argument
ValueTypeName ( arg ) : the type of the MDX argument when evaluated
```

For example:

```
VarTypeName   ( [Measures].[Amount] ) : "measure" 
ValueTypeName ( [Measures].[Amount] ) : "double"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to the new udpate.